# Global array for ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to include an array which stocks the information of a model. Whenever an object of model A is created, the attribute **name** of this object is added in the array and this array won't be re-set when I restart the server. I try put the array to the associated model class and controller, but it does not work. Can you tell me how to do this?

Comment: How is this different rom reading a single column from the DB: `ModelA.pluck(:name)`, it's an array and it's for free (no custom code needed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is every name of every ModelA that is stored in the DB?

According to @Leito, this would work:

```
ModelA.all.pluck(:name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:
`Model.all.uniq.pluck(:name)`, which translates to `SELECT DISTINCT name FROM models`